# What's the name of smd buttons build of a simple thin metal sheet which flex when pressed?

Tags: switches, surface-mount

As the topic title, I tried to find them but cannot get any informations about.
They are a sort of SMD tact switch made only by a very thin curved metal sheet. When you press they flex and make contact with the pcb or similar. I would like to post an image but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the part that flexes, it's called a "dome" or "snap dome". Photo from [this](https://www.pannam.com/blog/rubber-metal-dome-keypad/) site.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Digikey carries little SMD tactile switches, barely more than a thin piece that kind of pops down when pressed to make contact.
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/e-switch/TL3315NF100Q/EG4620CT-ND/1870400
[image]

Dome is apparently purchasable too:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/keystone-electronics/5134TR/36-5134CT-ND/6834346

> Keypad domes are designed to be placed on PCB, not soldered

http://www.keyelco.com/product-pdf.cfm?p=14314

So something needs to go over them to hold them in place.